# Confusion with notation P[event in dy]

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

What does it mean when people write: $\Pr \{ B \in dy \}\ $

What I don't understand is what $ dy$ in there means.

Comment: Informally, $dy$ denotes a small interval around $y$. $\operatorname{Pr}(B\in dy)$ denotes the density of the random variable $B$ at $y$ with respect to Lebesgue measure times $dy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $B$ is a random variable, let's call it $X$ for the sake of clarity ($B$ is usually a set name). Then if the $X$ has some probability density $f$, then  $P(X \in dy)$ means $f(y)dy$.

The intuition comes from the fact that if for a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ then
$$ P(X \in A) = \int_A f(y)dy$$ 
thus $f(y)dy$ measures the probability of $X$ being in an infinitesimal neighborhood of $y$